# using milkshape3d SDK in loading MS3D file

Tags: loader, directx-11, 3d-model

I'm loading an animation model using DirectX 11. Now I'm at the step of parsing MS3D model file and I am planing on using the MS3D SDK (http://www.milkshape3d.com/) for loading MS3D model. But it seems that this SDK is used for writing plugin in Milkshape Modeling Software, instead of in an independent program. The example attached in SDK is a DLL as below:

```
cMsPlugIn* CreatePlugIn ()
{
    return new cPlugIn ();
}

int cPlugIn::Execute (msModel *pModel)
{
    //process the model here.
}
```

The problem is that I the pointer msModel is passed into DLL, and I don't know how to create it from MS3D file.

I read the specification of this library relating to msModel structure, as it is listed as below.

```
/**********************************************************************
 * msModel
 **********************************************************************/

MSLIB_API void          msModel_Destroy (msModel *pModel);

MSLIB_API int           msModel_GetMeshCount (msModel *pModel);
MSLIB_API int           msModel_AddMesh (msModel *pModel);
MSLIB_API msMesh*       msModel_GetMeshAt (msModel *pModel, int nIndex);
MSLIB_API int           msModel_FindMeshByName (msModel *pModel, const char *szName);

MSLIB_API int           msModel_GetMaterialCount (msModel *pModel);
MSLIB_API int           msModel_AddMaterial (msModel *pModel);
MSLIB_API msMaterial*   msModel_GetMaterialAt (msModel *pModel, int nIndex);
MSLIB_API int           msModel_FindMaterialByName (msModel *pModel, const char         *szName);

MSLIB_API int           msModel_GetBoneCount (msModel *pModel);
MSLIB_API int           msModel_AddBone (msModel *pModel);
MSLIB_API msBone*       msModel_GetBoneAt (msModel *pModel, int nIndex);
MSLIB_API int           msModel_FindBoneByName (msModel *pModel, const char *szName);

MSLIB_API int           msModel_SetFrame (msModel *pModel, int nFrame);
MSLIB_API int           msModel_GetFrame (msModel *pModel);
MSLIB_API int           msModel_SetTotalFrames (msModel *pModel, int nTotalFrames);
MSLIB_API int           msModel_GetTotalFrames (msModel *pModel);
MSLIB_API void          msModel_SetPosition (msModel *pModel, msVec3 Position);
MSLIB_API void          msModel_GetPosition (msModel *pModel, msVec3 Position);
MSLIB_API void          msModel_SetRotation (msModel *pModel, msVec3 Rotation);
MSLIB_API void          msModel_GetRotation (msModel *pModel, msVec3 Rotation);
MSLIB_API void          msModel_SetCamera (msModel *pModel, msVec3 Position, msVec2     RotationXY);
MSLIB_API void          msModel_GetCamera (msModel *pModel, msVec3 Position, msVec2     RotationXY);
MSLIB_API void          msModel_SetComment (msModel *pModel, const char *pszComment);
MSLIB_API int           msModel_GetComment (msModel *pModel, char *pszComment, int     nMaxCommentLength);
MSLIB_API void          msModel_SetFileName (msModel *pModel, const char *pszFileName);
MSLIB_API int           msModel_GetFileName (msModel *pModel, char *pszFileName, int nMaxFileNameLength);
```

There's function like:

```
msModel_Destroy(msModel *pModel),
```

but there's no function like

```
msModel * msModel_Destroy(char* file_name);
```

I want to ask there's any way to work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have just found out the source code for loading MS3D model from the software MilkShape 3D Binary Model Viewer, which is at the link: http://www.milkshape3d.com/